# How do I plot this dataframes first and second columns as coordinates and the third as the size of the points?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

The dataframe is as follows:

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0.005 | 0.004 | 359 |
| 0.007 | 0.004 | 320 |
| 0.009 | 0.004 | 316 |
| 0.005 | 0.008 | 359 |
| 0.007 | 0.008 | 320 |
| 0.009 | 0.008 | 316 |

I would also like to label each point on the graph with its corresponding size from column three.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67353268/how-do-i-plot-the-first-column-of-a-dataframe-as-the-x-axis-the-second-column-a

Answer (score -1, accepted):

With `ggplot2`:

```
df <- read.table(text="
col1    col2    col3
0.005   0.004   359
0.007   0.004   320
0.009   0.004   316
0.005   0.008   359
0.007   0.008   320
0.009   0.008   316",header=T)

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df,aes(x=col1,y=col2,label=col3)) + geom_point(aes(size=col3)) +
                                           geom_text(vjust=2)
```

[image]